# Dynamically select a cell inside For statement

Tags: excel, vba

I want to dynamically select a cell, in column B, inside a For statement.

However I get:
"Application-defined or object-defined error"

How can I do this properly?

```
For i = 1 To 30
Sheets("Back").Range(Cells(i + 3, 2)).Select

Select Case ActiveCell.Value

Case "3"
Sheets("Back").Cells(i + 3, 2).Value = "Good"

Case "8"
Sheets("Back").Cells(i + 3, 2).Value = "Bad"


Case Else
Sheets("Back").Cells(i + 3, 2).Value = ""

End Select

Next i
```

Comment: Please see [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA macros](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/11683)

Comment: Ok. I will do that to improve the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

For i = 1 To 30

```
        Sheets("Back").Cells(i + 3, 2).Select

        Select Case ActiveCell.Value

        Case "3"
        Sheets("Back").Cells(i + 3, 2).Value = "Good"

        Case "8"
        Sheets("Back").Cells(i + 3, 2).Value = "Bad"


        Case Else
        Sheets("Back").Cells(i + 3, 2).Value = ""

        End Select
```

Next i